# Preventing fedora from installing mariadb

Tags: linux, mariadb, fedora, yum, percona

I'm running Fedora 24, with kde plasma, having recently decided to try it after mostly being on Ubuntu.

This morning while trying to update, I ran into a conflict between mariadb and percona. I had installed percona from rpms (since I couldn't install 5.7 from repos), but mariadb isn't installed, so I'm a little surprised.

According to the update note it relates to this bug:https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1352946

Which is all well and good, but now I'm getting:

```
Sep 19 09:57:48 SUBDEBUG 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 60, in main
    return _main(base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 120, in _main
    ret = resolving(cli, base)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 149, in resolving
    base.do_transaction(display=displays)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dnf/cli/cli.py", line 228, in do_transaction
    super(BaseCli, self).do_transaction(display)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 591, in do_transaction
    self._trans_error_summary(errstring))
dnf.exceptions.Error: Transaction check error:
  file /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/dialog.so from install of mariadb-common-3:10.1.17-1.fc24.x86_64 conflicts with file from package Percona-Server-server-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysql from install of mariadb-3:10.1.17-1.fc24.x86_64 conflicts with file from package Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqladmin from install of mariadb-3:10.1.17-1.fc24.x86_64 conflicts with file from package Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlbinlog from install of mariadb-3:10.1.17-1.fc24.x86_64 conflicts with file from package Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlcheck from install of mariadb-3:10.1.17-1.fc24.x86_64 conflicts with file from package Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqldump from install of mariadb-3:10.1.17-1.fc24.x86_64 conflicts with file from package Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlimport from install of mariadb-3:10.1.17-1.fc24.x86_64 conflicts with file from package Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlshow from install of mariadb-3:10.1.17-1.fc24.x86_64 conflicts with file from package Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/mysqlslap from install of mariadb-3:10.1.17-1.fc24.x86_64 conflicts with file from package Percona-Server-client-57-5.7.10-3.1.el7.x86_64
.
.<SNIP>
.
.
```

Maria is in the normal  fedora repos - is there any way to tell Fedora to NOT install mariadb via update?

The puzzling thing for me is why it's trying to install it. Have I done something stupid?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Had to go back to gnome 3 and uninstall kde, then the problem disappeared. Guess the issue was kde.